# Как рисовать на представлении? Qt

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

Есть модель, содержащая строки, и списочное представление.

Представление `QListView` является потомком `QPaintDevice`, следовательно в нём можно переопределить `paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)` и нарисовать на нём что-то. Например, нужно нарисовать (точнее напечатать уже готовый при помощи `QPainter::drawPixmap())` файл *cheker.png*:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QListView>
#include <QStringListModel>

class View :public QListView {
public:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
        QListView::paintEvent(event);
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawPixmap(10,10,QPixmap("cheker.png"));         
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QStringListModel model;
    QStringList list;
    list << "a" << "b" << "c" << "d" << "e" << "f" << "g" << "h";
    model.setStringList(list);

    View view;
    view.setModel(&model);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Не происходит того, что ожидается - картинка не печатается. Представление изображается так, как если бы никакие методы не переопределялись. А в консоль печатается следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как, собственно, рисовать на представлении?

Comment: Вы забыли Q_OBJECT

Comment: решено https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58492815/how-to-draw-on-a-view/58493159#58493159